# Firefox/IE play streamed MP3 (Served with PHP)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, streaming, mp3

I'm having trouble playing a locally created mp3 through firefox and IE, although they work fine in Chrome.

The file is basically this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file_name.'.mp3"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('files/'.$file_name.'.mp3'));

ob_clean();
flush();

readfile('files/'.$file_name.'.mp3');

exit();
```

I don't get any type of error in IE, but in firefox I'm met with:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg3" is not supported. Load of media resource [url here]
```

I tried it with just `audio/mpeg` as the content-type but had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firefox does not generally support MP3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

Also, the correct content type is `audio/mpeg`.  The others you are using are not correct.

Comment: Ah thanks, looks like ogg might be the way forward in this case.